# How do I set a schema level default engine? [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, schema

I'm trying to set a default database engine for each of my MySQL schemas, but I can't seem to find out how to do that.

I know it's possible to specify the engine at the table level, and in the config file with  `--default-storage-engine=type`, but isn't there a way to set it at the schema level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can set the engine to use in the CREATE TABLE statement, or you can set the default using the --default-storage-engine server startup option, or by setting the default-storage-engine option in the my.cnf configuration file. Finally you can set the default storage engine to be used during the current session by setting the storage_engine variable storage_engine.

There's no default schema storage engine.